# Selenium 3.0 does not run on firefox on the grid

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid

When I run my scripts using Selenium 3.0 on the grid, only firefox instances open and nothing happens.

My setup is like this:
Selenium - 3.0.0

Selenium Grid - hub and node started using Selenium 3.0.0 and with below options:

hub - 
    java -jar selenium-server-standalone.jar -role hub -timeout 300000

node - 
    java -Dwebdriver.gecko.driver=C:\Grid2\geckodriver-v0.11.1-win64\geckodriver.exe -jar  selenium-server-standalone.jar -role node -hub http://localhost:4444/grid/register -port 5556 -nodeConfig se2config.txt

se2config.txt contents -

```
{

  "capabilities":
  [
    {
      "browserName": "firefox",
      "maxInstances": 1,
      "seleniumProtocol": "WebDriver"
    },
    {
      "browserName": "chrome",
      "maxInstances": 1,
      "seleniumProtocol": "WebDriver"
    },
    {
      "browserName": "internet explorer",
      "maxInstances": 1,
      "seleniumProtocol": "WebDriver"
    }
  ],
  "proxy": "org.openqa.grid.selenium.proxy.DefaultRemoteProxy",
  "maxSession": 1,
  "port": 5556,
  "register": true,
  "registerCycle": 5000,
  "hub": "http://localhost:4444",
  "nodeStatusCheckTimeout": 5000,
  "nodePolling": 5000,
  "role": "node",
  "unregisterIfStillDownAfter": 60000,
  "downPollingLimit": 2,
  "debug": false,
  "servlets" : [],
  "withoutServlets": [],
  "custom": {}
    }
```

Firefox version - 47.0.2

Added geckodriver.exe path to PATH variable and also in the code using:

```
    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","<path>")
```

The scripts run fine locally, but when run on the grid, it just launches the firefox browser and does not do anything.

Following are the node logs:

```
Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:91)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:141)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:82)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:601)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:241)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:128)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:259)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:247)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:242)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:135)
    ... 14 more
```

02:22:31.173 WARN - Exception: Unable to create new remote session. desired capabilities = Capabilities [{marionette=true, firefoxOptions=org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxOptions@268c4f21, browserName=firefox, moz:firefoxOptions=org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxOptions@268c4f21, version=, platform=ANY, firefox_profile=UEsDBBQACAgIAIx2eUkAAAAAAAAAA...}], required capabilities = Capabilities [{}]
Build info: version: '3.0.0', revision: '350cf60', time: '2016-10-13 10:48:16 -0700'
The scr

I run the scripts from my local system and it gets executed on the grid node.

1.So what other changes or additions do I make to run tests on the grid.

2.Also, if I were to run my tests using jenkins, so since the code will be built on the jenkins node, how can I set the -Dwebdriver path for node, does it have to be the path of geckodriver on the jenkins slave or of that of the grid node.

Comment: which firefox version are you using on your grid machine?

Comment: firefox version : 47.0.2